# How to get input content from GET or POST request in CGI program (via apache)?

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi

I'm studying making a CGI program.
Now I can print text what I want.
But how can I get GET or POST input from CGI program? (such as query-string or post-body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query string is accessible via the environmental variable called REQUEST_URI.
If the client sent a POST request, then the contents will be available through the standard input.

See [the Apache tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/cgi.html) for a brief info (this is where the above sentences have been copied from).

By the way, most scripting language provides some kind of CGI support (for example, perl's CGI documentation is [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html)), so the one you use surely has methods for extracting data from the request as well.